# why the DevTools stops showing network traffic

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, stetho

On Mac and for android app, used to use chrome://inspect and pick the emulator running that app. And in the devTools form (when app integrate with stetho) it used to show left pane for listing the network calls and right pane showing the details for individual call.
But today the devTools does not show any of the network traffic at all (and no left pane).

What could be wrong or changed (from app's code wise, nothing changed).

the chrome versio:
Version 89.0.4389.82 (Official Build) (x86_64)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

looks like it is a known issue https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/696,
and reinstall 87.0.4280.88 made it work. But it says "Relaunch Google Chrome to finish updating". For how long it can stay not to relaunch?

[image]